# Create a batch file to search all .csv files inside folder and set all file name to variable?

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

I am trying to search all filename with .csv extension inside a folder and assign the csv file names to a variable and execute my script using for loop.

testfolder-> file1.csv ,file2.csv, file3.csv

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%f in (C:\Desktop\test\*.csv) do (
    echo "fullname: %%f"
    echo "name: %%~nf"
    set p = %%~nf 

    set TC=Script.vu
    set env_csv=C:\csv\env\envfile.csv
    echo %env_csv%
    set data_csv=C:\csv\data\%p%.csv
    echo %data_csv%

    set pyfile = "c:\pythonfile.py"

    set testcode=
%pyfile% -tc "%TC%" -datapath "%data_csv%" -envpath "%env_csv%"


    if %testcode% == 0 (
        echo  created Successfully.

    ) else (
        echo creation failed.
    )


    pause

)
```

I am unable to use for loop properly and set file name.

Comment: when using variables modified in for loops, you need to use !expansion! not %expansion%. Additionally, when defining variables, any space between the variable name and the `=` will be **Included** in the variable name. testcode is never defined.
Most, if not all of the variables you define are unnecessary as where they are expanded you could just use the For loop variable with modifier.

Comment: can you please explain in code. I did not get you sorry for that

Comment: I have tried to format the code you posted, to both show indentations, _(for clarity)_, and to better highlight the `%pyfile%` line, _(which I assume was intended to be on the line above)_. This then shows that you wrongly thought that `%testcode%` would hold the error level from running a `.py` file. That is not the case, what you were probably looking for was to remove `set testcode=` and replace `%testcode%` with `%ErrorLevel%`. Your other issues have already been highlighted in another comment, so I will not repeat them.